# How to avoid Sleep mode in ubuntu server 32x

Tags: 12.04, server, suspend

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/ubuntu-server-continuously-goes-to-sleep/25151#25151

I try the upper solution to avoid my Ubuntu server (32x) to sleep, but now i just can't enter it, after i reboot aparently something avoid it enter to the console, it start to boot but don't end.

in my case just shows the console while booting, but the one with very big Letters on it and not a chance of write anything on it, like the lines of console who apparead when is turned on, but don't leave that state.

i don't have any gui installed and i really preffer fix the problem through terminal

Any question? please do it

Thanks in advance

PS: i can't modify the "grub" back like it was before the change, so i can't revert the changes done.

My version is 12.04

Comment: i doubt it, in my case apparead the console while booting, but the one with very big Letters on it.

Comment: The indicated question is also for users who might not boot *directly* to a black screen, but still do.